# node-config how can I dynamically set property

Tags: node.js, dynamic, properties, config

Using node-config, is there anyway to do

```
var config = require('config');
config.ip = someIp;
```

I need to get my ips dynamically and use them in my config.  Is there anyway to do this?

I tried just setting it but it's a read only property.  I also looked at the code but could not see a way to do it.  Please don't make me change my config framework :(

thanks,

R

Comment: You can store your config in a js file. Since its a js file you can change the properties dynamically.

Comment: aha! or duh! hmm, yea, I should have thought of that! I'll try that now.  Thanks.  That said .... seems like I shouldn't have to do that.  Why not let me modify my freakin config file programmaticly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So I guess I found the answer.  If you declare

```
process.env['ALLOW_CONFIG_MUTATIONS']=true;
```

Then you can use the set method on config values.  To be specific, you can set 'ALLOW_CONFIG_MUTATIONS' to anything besides null or undefined and it should work.